# Is there a more efficient way to use Ajax when updating a form?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a HTML form that allows users to filter their choices when browsing. There are multiple fields (radio button groups) that when the user clicks on them, the search results are updated accordingly.

I'm doing this with an Ajax call to results.php and passing a different variable depending on the radio button group that has been clicked - like so:

```
 <script>
  
  $('input[type=radio][name=data]').on('change', function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "results.php",
       data: "monthlydata=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(response){  

      $('#results').show(1000).html(response);
      

      }
      
    });
  });      

   $('input[type=radio][name=contract_length]').on('change', function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "results.php",
       data: "contract_length=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(response){  

      $('#results').show(1000).html(response);
      

      }
      
    });
  });      

    $('input[type=radio][name=price]').on('change', function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "results.php",
       data: "price=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(response){  

      $('#results').show(1000).html(response);
      

      }
      
    });
  });    

  $('input[type=radio][name=mbprice]').on('change', function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "results.php",
       data: "price=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(response){  

      $('#results').show(1000).html(response);
      

      }
      
    });
  });  
   $('input[type=radio][name=mbcontract_length]').on('change', function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "results.php",
       data: "contract_length=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(response){  

      $('#results').show(1000).html(response);
      

      }
      
    });
  });  

    $('input[type=radio][name=mbdata]').on('change', function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "results.php",
       data: "monthlydata=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(response){  

      $('#results').show(1000).html(response);
      

      }
      
    });
  });
```

This works fine but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way of achieving the result. Is there another way of achieving the same thing with less code?

Comment: If your code works and you just want someone to review it and suggest potential improvements, please post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a possible solution if all the radio button groups are filters and their name correspond to the query variable name

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {

     $.ajax({
         
       type: "POST",
       url: "results.php",
       data: $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val(),
       
       success: function(response){  
         $('#results').show(1000).html(response);
       }
      
    });
});
```

if you can't use always the same name for the input and the search parameter, you can also (optionally) add the name to the input as data attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="mbprice" data-name="price">
```

then in the ajax call you can pass data in this way:

```
data: (typeof $(this).data("name") !== "undefined" ? $(this).data("name") : $(this).attr("name")) + "=" + $(this).val(),
```

this should work too:

```
data: ($(this).data("name") || $(this).attr("name")) + "=" + $(this).val(),
```

Comment: @bertster I've added an improvement to the answer